# Do CSS / HTML children override parents?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, operator-precedence

Given the following code:

```
<div id="bla">
    <p class="blubber">Johnny Bananas</p>
</div>
```

and the style in head of that html doc:

```
<style>
    div#bla{background:yellow}
    p.blubber{background:purple}
</style>
```

Why is it that the child will be coloured purple and overlay its parent?

Comment: Why don't you just try it and see what happens?

Comment: @WTP: He already did, and is asking why it happens.

Comment: @BoltClock whoops, think I read it wrongly, my bad. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `background` property is not inherited by children by default. Therefore, the background style of `div#bla` does not apply to `p.blubber`, and `p.blubber` can specify its own background color independently of its parent and regardless of specificity.

And since `background` isn't being inherited, no overriding actually takes place.

Comment: So children nodes in the DOM do overlap their parents in the z-index stack?

Answer (score 0):

When multiple style sheets are used, the style sheets may fight over control of a particular selector. In these situations, there must be rules as to which style sheet's rule will win out. The following characteristics will determine the outcome of contradictory style sheets.

check out the section on cascading order - http://htmlhelp.com/reference/css/structure.html

Comment: These selectors don’t apply to the same element though.

Comment: but they do, its cascading specificity.

Comment: ah, no, I meant the *selectors* don’t select the same element. `div#bla` selects the `<div>`, and `p.blubber` selects the `<p>`. Therefore the cascade (i.e. the set of rules that decides which conflicting declaration should apply) doesn’t come into play here.

Answer (score 0):

Because the specificity is the same, so the rule will apply to the `p` element. If you remove the `p` and just have `.blubber`, it wouldn't work.

Also, children can't override parents, so if there were more content, you'd see yellow around the `p` (add padding to the `div`).

Background color is not and inherited attribute in CSS.

Comment: “If you remove the p and just have .blubber, it wouldn't work.” [Yes it would](http://jsfiddle.net/pauldwaite/R2PwG/) — each selector selects different elements.

Comment: Also, the specificity is different.

Comment: true.. well it's late and i'm sleep deprived, sorry for the bad info :-)